# Show() Hide () element without CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now i use show/hide with slideToggle and with CSS display: none

current code below:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            $('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
</script>
```

and HTML

```
<div id="showmenu">Show</div>  
<br/>
<div class="menu2" style="display: none;">    
hidden text here
</div>
```

But I need to use this without CSS ( I can't use "display: none")

tried to use google :), read documentation, but still didn't find any ways to make it without css. hope for your help!

Comment: I use image cropping plugin in hidden filed, and when I hide element with "display none" and then toggle it, image not cropping.

Comment: If you really can't use CSS, you can always remove the node from DOM but have JS store it in a var... I'd really look at your plugin first though. You can't really fix display issues without CSS...

Comment: _“I use image cropping plugin in hidden filed, and when I hide element with "display none" and then toggle it, image not cropping”_ – that might perhaps just be an issue of _when_ that plugin is initialized for/added onto the element.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to position it outside of the screen boundaries? (e.g. position: absolute; and left: -10000px;). Then bring it back when needed...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing opacity to 0.  And then setting pointer-events to none to make it unclickable.

```
$('#showmenu').click(function() {
        $( ".menu" ).fadeTo( "fast" , 0.0, function() {
             $( ".menu" ).css( 'pointer-events', 'none' );
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant use

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            $('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
    });
$('.menu').hide();
});
</script>
```

if not you can use hide() show() try

```
    <script>
        var menu = $('.menu');
         $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#showmenu').click(function() {
                if($('.menu').length ==0)
                        $('div#div_menu').append($(menu));
                else
                        $('.menu').remove();
        });
    });
    </script>
```